# If$x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=x(y+z+t)$prove $x=y=z=t=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sum-of-squares-method

> If
>
> $$x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=x(y+z+t)$$ Prove $x=y=z=t=0$

I added $x^2$ to both side of the equation:

$$x^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=x(x+y+z+t)$$
Then rewrite it as:
$$x^2+(x+y+z+t)^2-2(xy+xz+xt+yz+yt+zt)=x(x+y+z+t)$$
$$x^2+(x+y+z+t)(y+z+t)=2(xy+xz+xt+yz+yt+zt)$$
But it doesn't seem useful.

Comment: You can write this as $$\Big(y-\frac{x}{2}\Big)^2+\Big(z-\frac{x}{2}\Big)^2+\Big(t-\frac{x}{2}\Big)^2=-\frac{x^2}{4}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the beautiful identity $$y^2+z^2+t^2=\frac{1}{3}\left({(y+z+t)}^2+{(y-z)}^2+{(z-t)}^2+{(t-y)}^2\right)$$  thus we have $$x^2+\frac{1}{3}{(y+z+t)}^2+\frac{{(y-z)}^2+{(z-t)}^2+{(t-y)}^2}{3}=x(y+z+t)$$ $${\left (x-\frac{(y+z+t)}{2}\right)}^2+ \frac{{(y+z+t)}^2}{12}+\frac{{(y-z)}^2+{(z-t)}^2+{(t-y)}^2}{3}=0$$  which means $x=y=z=t=0$

(As its a sum of squares each term must be zero)

Comment: Nice solution. how you recognized this method? to me it is really far from the mind!

Comment: @Soheil This method is used in inequalities it is called the sum of squares method ,the first identity is the proof of Cauchy schwarz inequality for three variables the other one I was just looking fro a perfect square and it came.Its used in contest inequalities

Comment: @Soheil an alternative way is to see this as a quadratic in $x$ and the dicriminant is $\ge 0$ only when $y=z=t$  after whcih your work is easy

Comment: Nice. We could have also re-written the expression as $\frac{x^2}{4} + \Big(y-\frac{x}{2}\Big)^2+\Big(z-\frac{x}{2}\Big)^2+\Big(t-\frac{x}{2}\Big)^2=0$. That leads to $x = 0$ and hence rest of them as zero.

Comment: @MathLover agreed  but that was already mentioned in the comments ,any way I felt this was 'cooler' although  more convoluted

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore this seems really cool. but I can't solve the inequality $(y+z+t)^2 \ge 4(y^2+z^2+t^2)$ by the way I would be glad if you write this alternative method as another answer.

Comment: @Soheil how about thats equavalent to $$-y^2-z^2-t^2-{(y-z)}^2-{(z-t)}^2-{(t-y)}^2\ge 0$$ I think its correct now which means $y=z=t=0$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Yess, I got it. I think it is true. but it is really far from my mind too;)

Answer (score 1):

hint: $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=(\frac{x^2}{3}+y^2)+(\frac{x^2}{3}+z^2)+(\frac{x^2}{3}+t^2)
=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}-y)^2+(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}-z)^2+(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}-t)^2+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot x(y+z+t)\geqslant 0+1\cdot x(y+z+t)$

When would the equality hold?

Comment: I can't see how you  obtain the inequality. I know the squares are minimum when they are equal to zero

Comment: $a=x(y+z+t)=x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2\geqslant 0, \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}>1, so \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot a\geqslant 1\cdot a$. And (for this part alone) when equality holds $a$ must be 0.

Comment: I got it. Very good trick! $+1$

Answer (score 1):

less beautiful

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Back substitution says $t=0$  then $z=0$ then $y=0$ then $x=0.$   All that is going on is that the matrix I am calling $H$ is positive definite. With all real variables, each row in my $Q$ must indicate a zero vector ( when multiplied by $(x,y,z,t)^T \; \; \; \; $ )

Answer (score 1):

We have$$x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=x(y+z+t)\iff x^2-\frac34x^2+(y-\frac x2)^2+(z-\frac x2)^2+(t-\frac x2)^2=0$$ i.e.$$\left(\frac x2\right)^2+\left(y-\frac x2\right)^2+\left(z-\frac x2\right)^2+\left(t-\frac x2\right)^2=0$$
We are done

Comment: Hi @Piquito, I feel a little guilty that you have attempted two answers on a recent question and for some reason neither has been given due encouragement. I also think your threat of quitting MSE makes this a serious issue. Can you tell me your side of things? I genuinely wish to help you out. You can visit this chatroom, I will be here for sometime from this comment : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119549/teresa-lisbon-senior-agent-cbi